# Amazon Application Load Balancer Host Based Routing to a specific ECS Container Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs, elastic-load-balancer

I'm new to ECS & ALB in AWS's universe, and i'd like to know how can i point my App in the front end to a specific ECS service.

Should I give it maybe the :port or /service_name ?
and if i'd like to use Host-Based Routing, and i use my own DNS subdomains. 
For Example :

```
 <service>.hostname.com ,
```

How can i point each service to it's corresponding one in the ECS cluster through the Application Load Balancer ?

Comment: Hi @Ayoub , could you add more into what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: All right then ! let's suppose that i have multiple apps, each app uses a service that belongs to the ECS cluster, the trafic is load balanced and routed using an Elastic ALB. I want to know which URL should use to point each app to it's specific service behind the ALB. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Amazon's [Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html), you associate your services with [Target Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html). You can then create [rules on your listeners that say which traffic to send to which Target Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html). Application Load Balancer supports two different rule types: Host (eg: `service1.hostname.com`) and Path (eg: `/service1`).

So the basic things you need to do are:

1. Create a target group for each service
2. Create a rule sending the hosts/paths you want to the target group
3. Associate each service with its associated target group

Comment: should i associate all hosts with the ALB DNS ?

Comment: If you're going with the `Host` based rules, then Yes. If you're using Route53, you would also likely benefit from using [Aliases](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) to the ALB's DNSName, as this then has the zones resolved directly by the ALBs Resource Records, which saves you money, removes DNS hops, and ensures that the IPs are updated when the underlying ALBs IPs change.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jamie
(a Lannister or a Starke xD - just kidding)